# How to do Component Pooling in React?

Tags: performance, reactjs, components

In device with limited resources, it is common practice to leverage performance by Component Pooling. For example, there is a endless scroll list. Since there is always around 10 components shown in viewport, we can have only 20 components instances in pool. When user scrolls up or down, components at top or bottom is switched to other side and filled with new data. In such a way, user feels the list is long, but it takes only 20 component instances.

With jQuery and imperative programming, it is easy to implement such Component Pooling trick. However, in React world, UI is declarative.

```
const List = ({listData}) => {
  return <ul>
    {listData.map(item => <li>{item}</li>);
  </ul>;
}
```

The code just declares that there is a list of items to be shown. Our code doesn't have control to make component pooling; and I believe React itself will create DOM pooling.

So, how to implement Component Pooling for better performance?

Answer (score 3):

The [React-Virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) library is the go-to implementation of virtual lists for use in React apps.  It's pretty heavily optimized, and I think it uses a lot of refs and DOM interaction to accomplish what it needs to do.

That said, while I've never actually *tried* to implement a virtual list or component pooling in React (or elsewhere, really), I could picture something that *might* be along the right lines for a basic concept.

For this example, we've got a list of 1000 items, but only want to show 20.  To start with, you'd do all the proper pagination and windowing in `render`.  Let's say the user has scrolled down 30 items, so we want to display items 30-50.  Typically, when you render a list of items in React, you'd assign keys to each item based on IDs from the data, or as a fallback, array indices.

Normally, using array indices as keys is bad, because changing the contents makes React think that stuff has been shifted around.  Instead of having components mount and unmount, as you'd *usually* want, the components would stay mounted but suddenly receive a different set of props.  But, in this case, that would seem to be the desired behavior.

So, totally untested and hypothetical but vaguely plausible example code:

```
render() {
    const {items} = this.props;
    const {displaySize, startIndex} = this.state;

    const itemsToDisplay = items.slice(startIndex, startIndex + displaySize + 1);

    const renderedItems = itemsToDisplay.map( (item, index) => {
        return <ListItem item={item} key={index} />
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {renderedItems}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention, Mark! One small thing to point out about the example is that it would cause unnecessary DOM updates as each time the start index changed all of the elements would be updated b'c each element's key would shift. You could try rotating keys (eg `(startIndex + index) % poolSize`) so long as the pool size is stable. With RV I've found it better to just set keys to `startIndex + index` but YMMV.

Comment: Bah, a rotating key should have been `(startIndex + index) % (displaySize + 1)`